# QNetworkReply не возвращает значение QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader заголовка

Tags: c++, qt, http, header

Нужно получить значение заголовка `Content-Disposition` из `QNetworkReply`.

```
reply->header(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader) // QVariant(invalid)
reply->rawHeader("Content-Disposition") // "attachment; filename=\"securitywidget.o\""
```

Не могу понять в чем прикол. Как можно нормально получить имя файла, максимально не прибегая к парсингу?

Comment: `"Date" "Tue, 10 Oct 2017 14:09:59 GMT" zzz"Server" "Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)" zzz"Expires" "Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT" zzz"Cache-Control" "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0" zzz"Pragma" "no-cache" zzz"Content-Length" "1519314" zzz"Content-Disposition" "attachment; filename=\"securitywidget.o\"" zzz"Keep-Alive" "timeout=5, max=100" zzz"Connection" "Keep-Alive" zzz"Content-Type" "application/binary" zzz` вывод `reply->rawHeaderList()` с разделителем `zzz`

Comment: Не знаю, скажу только что видимо не только у Вас это возникало 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208821/reading-the-final-name-of-a-file-downloaded-using-qnetworkaccessmanager

Comment: @Alex да, я видел это, но думал, что с 2009 года эта проблема решилась. Пока что вытащил имя регуляркой, но уже просто интересно что за магия в `Qt` творится)

Comment: Есть [`net::HttpContentDisposition` из Chromium](https://cs.chromium.org/search/?q=net::HttpContentDisposition&sq=package:chromium&type=cs)

Comment: так а что не так? rawHeader не возвращает ничего?

Comment: @Xplatforms `rawHeader` как раз возвращает необработанные данные, но тогда приходится их парсить регуляркой, что не круто. Но даже не в этом проблема. Просто не понятно почему так происходит. Баги Qt'a?

Comment: Он по этому и называется **raw**Header. Это не баг.

Comment: @Xplatforms -_- Читайте внимательнее. С `rawHeader` проблем нет, `header` не возвращает ничего...

Comment: понял, мой косяк.